# How to tap a view that's underneath another view with voiceover

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a UICollectionView with a contentInset at the top.

[image: UICV Behind]
[image: UICV Behind and scrolled]

In the contentInset area, is the `Top View`. The top view is physically behind the UICV, with hit testing that passes the touches through to the TopView. ie: Touches in the TopView area pass through the UICV and are recognized by the TopView.

However the when tapping in the TopView with the accessibility inspector (or in VoiceOver mode on device), it selects the UICollectionView

[image]

Is there a way to make VoiceOver select the TopView in my example?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I’m running into the same use case.